# Open Windows Phone 8 local file with IE

Tags: 8.0, internet

I've put an HTML file in the Documents folder of my Windows 8 phone (Nokia 920) and I'd like to open it with the phone's Internet Explorer, but can't figure out the correct URL.

Comment: sorry but this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is not possible.